# ASP.NET: Linq2SQL: selecting all names matching an id

Tags: asp.net, linq

Got 2 tables: db.Tags (ID, TagName) and db.Names (ID, Name, TagID).

I want to fetch all db.Tags rows, and all the Names matching the TagID.

So it will look like

```
ID - TagName - Names
1  - tag1    - name1, name2, name3
2  - tag2    - name4, name5, name6
```

Is this possible in one (long) linq query?
or do I have to get all the tags, then do foreach tag, get all the names, then do foreach names to put them in a one long string..

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Okay see my comment on the second answer (first one up..), this is what i tried but i get some errors in compiler:

```
        var tags = 
        from t in db.Tags
        orderby t.Priority ascending
        select new {
            t.ID,
            t.Name,
            t.Priority,
            Places = String.Join(", ", 
                (from p in db.Places
                 join o in db.TagToPlaces on new {
                    p.ID,
                    t.ID
                 }
                 equals new {
                     o.PlaceId,
                     o.TagId
                 }
                 select p.Name
                 ).ToArray()
             ) 
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
var query =
    from t in db.Tags
    select new
    {
        t.ID,
        t.TagName,
        Names = String.Join(", ",
            (from n in db.Names
            where n.TagID == t.ID
            select n.Name)
            .ToArray()),
    };
```

With this I get the same sort of output that you gave in your question. I also understood that you want to output the tag id and name even when there are no associated name records - my query does that.

Now depending on if you're using EF or LINQ-to-SQL or something else you may need to add `.ToArray()` to the `db.Tags` & `db.Names` references to force the database query to occur.

If you have a large number of tag records you'll find you have a large number of queries going to the database. You could make this change to reduce it to only two queries:

```
var tags = db.Tags.ToArray();
var names = db.Names.ToArray();
var query =
    from t in tags
    select new
    {
        t.ID,
        t.TagName,
        Names = String.Join(", ",
            (from n in names
            where n.TagID == t.ID
            select n.Name)
            .ToArray()),
    };
```

Now you just need to make sure that your data fits into memory - but it sounds like it should. I hope this helps.

Comment: hmm.. first of all thanks!!! it think i misguided you a little bit.. i got confused myself.. anyway, i have 3 dbs, db.Tags (id, name, priority), db.Places (id, name), db.TagToPlaces (id,tagid, placeid).. so i want to display all tags names, and their corresponding placenames (as a list with ',') i know i kinda complicated right now, but thats what i need sorry :(

Comment: anyway i manged to get it working, just tweaked your query a litle bit.. so thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Since the concat is a pain in TSQL, I would query the 3 values "as is", and format from there:

```
var list = (from tag in db.Tags
           join name in db.Names
             on tag.ID equals name.TagId
           orderby tag.ID
           select new { tag.ID, tag.TagName, name.Name }).ToList();
```

for example, if I wanted the names by tag-id, I could do:

```
var namesByTag = list.ToLookup(row => row.ID, row => row.Name);
```

(or whatever else you choose)

Comment: the thing is, i'm using a repeater to parse all the data using databind. so thats why i want to use one query for it. so i could just eval "Names" and they will appear (with commas,)

Comment: @Nati - that **is** 1 query (to the database). You don't have to do everything at the DB; it is perfectly reasonable to fetch data from the DB in the way simplest for the DB, then re-shape it in you app tier. You can then cache it any which way you like.